# can I redirect file as input to notify-send?

Tags: bash, redirect, notify-send

I want to use command `notify-send` and display text from a file as a notification so that I can only edit that file to change command or forward contents from outputs of other programs to `notify-send`.

I tried :

- `notify-send -u critical -t 3000 < ~/ved`
- `cat ved | notify-send -u critical -t 3000`

It says : `No summary specified.`

What should I do about this summary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Im not sure what you want to do or what kind of file you want to display but `man notify-send` says

```
notify-send [OPTIONS] <summary> [body]
```

Summary being a title, so for example, the basename of your file.

So what you can do is

```
notify-send -u critical -t 3000 "$(basename ~/ved)" "$(cat ~/ved)"
```

But be aware that notify-send won't print long text file, it's not its job.

Also, I don't know for you or everyone else, but the **-t** option never worked for me, time being always 10s. I've read it was a bug a long time ago and it's still not working in 12.04.

Answer (score 15):

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4460/pipe-output-to-notify-send

says

```
echo 'information overlord' | while read OUTPUT; do notify-send "$OUTPUT"; done
```

Comment: One can also only forward the stderr to notify-osd. Here is an example: `git ls-remote "https://bitbucket.org/$username/$reponame.git" 2>&1 1>/dev/null | while read OUTPUT; do notify-send "error" "$OUTPUT" -i gtk-error; done`

Comment: Thanks. I added this to my `~/.bash_aliases`: `function notify { while read input; do notify-send "message" "$input"; done; }`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
notify-send -u critical -t 3000 "$(cat ~/ved)"
```

Comment: Without a proper summary, it will consider it as a title and will not break lines.